# Stop R Shiny from "listening" with Linux Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, shiny

I have used R Shiny in a Windows environment before. I am very new to Linux (a few days). I have downloaded Ubuntu (12.0.4) to try to run my R Shiny App.

To run R in Ubuntu I press `ctrl-alt-t` to start the Temrinal. Then type `R` in the terminal. And an R session starts in the terminal.

I have run these simple R codes:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
runGist("https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/3239667")
```

The app opens in Firefox and is totally functional. However, when I close the app. And go back to the R session in the terminal, I cannot do anything? I have to "kill" the app from listening by closing the terminal. Then going through all steps above again. Is there some command I should run before/after `runGist` so that I can tell shiny to stop running, such that I can easily resume my R session without having to kill everything?

In R Windows GUI I would just hit the escape key.

Comment: In general `Control-C` is the Unix analogue of `ESC` for R (i.e., "abort current action")

Comment: it is explicitly mentioned in shiny `runApp` help: `Interrupt R to stop the application (usually by pressing Ctrl+C or Esc).`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did not know of the crtl+c command in terminal. Appreciate your help with the silly/simple question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to send an [abort command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) to the terminal.

You could also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process running Shiny and then resume it with the foreground command `fg`.

Comment: Just a small followup question: is there a way to add this in a Rscript?
For instance I have the command `outliersAll <- visualize(data)`, which will start up Shiny. Can I add in some flag that will terminate this 'listening'?